# Rails with two sided multi select jquery plugin, weird error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm using the jquery plugin "Two Sided Multi Select" as per here:
http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/cmsfiles/assets/File/twosidedmultiselect.html

Successfully displaying a regular multi select box using regular rails helpers with this code:

```
<%= f.select(:expertise1, Tag.all.collect {|tag| [ tag.value, tag.value ] }, {}, {multiple: true, class: "multiselect"}) %>
```

I have the jquery.twosidedmultiselector.js  file in my javascripts folder in assets, and see it in the page source. Jquery must be loaded as using it all over the place (rails 3.2.8) and is visible in the source. (1.8.2)

However, when I add this to javascript (within $(document).ready(function()  ):

```
    $(".multiselect").twosidedmultiselect();
```

I get this error in the javascript console, which I have absolutely no idea what it means and how to fix it:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'twosidedmultiselect'
```

Help!! Many thanks.

Comment: moving the downloaded script into the document ready function (before) my call, makes the boxes show, but the buttons in between don't work...

Answer (score -1):

Encase your javascript in **DOM Ready handler** and that should solve the problem

```
$(function() {
     // This is the only line you need for the plugin
     $(".multiselect").twosidedmultiselect();

    // The below script is for information / example...

    // How to get the current selected items (note, they won't always have 
    // a "selected" attribute, but they will be in the box with the original ID:

    var selectedOptions = $("#yourselect")[0].options;

});
```

You seem to use the plugins before your elements are completely loaded .. Writing your code inside the DOM handler should solve your problem

Comment: Still the same as in my previous comment; the boxes show, but the buttons don't work and the right list stays empty... Has anyone been able to get this to work with Rails?? Also tried it on a clean Rails app; it works even without the downloaded code in document ready; but same issue; the buttons don't work, nothing happens. No javascript errors. Sigh, this is so poorly documented, anyone know any alternatives that achieve the same with Rails?

Comment: this is a great alternative thanks! Maybe update the question with this so its more obvious. Also, to install multis-select https://github.com/klenis/multi-select-rails on rails.